# Having Trouble Viewing Local Variable When Debuging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HKsT.png)
I just switch to Window to use VSCode and when i debug, I cannot view the vector variable. Its appear to be very complicated and i wonder if the problem has anything to do with my lauch.json, tasks.json, c_cpp_properties.json or settings.json
This is my c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x86",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86",
      "browse": {
        "path": [
          "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
      },
      "compilerArgs": [
        "-03"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-std=c++17"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
            
        }
    ]
}
```

lauch.json file below

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "c:/Users/DELL/Desktop/code",
      "program": "c:/Users/DELL/Desktop/code/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask" :  "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
    }
  ]
}
```

[This is when i debug in MacOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpMZl.png)

Comment: You forgot to install the STL pretty-printers for GDB, or install a new enough GDB that ships with them.